# If Clause Issue with img Generation

Tags: jquery, sorting, insert, move

Script is as follows;

```
$("#Results a").live('dblclick', function(event){
    var src = $(this).attr("href");
    if (event.type === 'dblclick') {
        if ($(this).hasClass(".A")) {
            $('<img />', {'src': src,'class': 'Box'}).wrap('<div class="Packet" />').parent().insertAfter($('.Spot_A').parent());
        } else if ($(this).hasClass(".B")) {
            $('<img />', {'src': src,'class': 'Box'}).wrap('<div class="Packet" />').parent().insertAfter($('.Spot_B').parent());
        }
    }
});
```

I double click a link tag to create an img element that uses the href of the link for the src of the image, and places this img somewhere specific, based on the class the link element had. The img element creation part works perfectly. However, i'm now trying to 'sort' the various imgs based on what class the link tag had. This is where i'm having trouble. To me, it seems dead obvious how it should go, but it fails to work.

I figured, it should simply be: When i double click a link, if this (the link) has class *_*_, create an img HERE. If a diff class, then create an img HERE. Note that the links aren't being deleted at any point.

The .parent/insertafter/parent part is necessary because its a part of how the placement within the hierarchy is determined. Spot_A/B is the starting point, and this is the key for the sorting.

Comment: Why are you checking for `event.type` ?! If `Spot_A/B` are the starting points, why are you doing `parent()` on them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass) takes the name of a class, not a class selector. Remove the periods.

```
if ($(this).hasClass("A")) {
    // stuff
} else if ($(this).hasClass("B")) {
    // other stuff
}
```

Giving this the full cleanup treatment:

```
$('#Results a').live('dblclick', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        src = $this.attr('href'),
        target = $this.hasClass('A') ? '.Spot_A'
               : $this.hasClass('B') ? '.Spot_B'
               : null;

    if (target) {
        $(target).parent().after($('<div class="Packet"></div>').append($('<img />', {'src': src, 'class': 'Box'})));
    }
});
```

- Don't repeatedly wrap `this`, store `$(this)` in a local variable
- There is no need to check for `event.type === 'dblclick'`
- Be consistent with single vs double quotes
- Stay DRY
- This is more a matter of personal preference, but a simple `if-else` case can be written more tersely with two sets of ternary operators
- As per [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2), tags that can contain other elements should be paired with a closing tag (when using `$()` to create new elements)
- Clean up the element creation calls

Comment: +1 for the list, code and catch. My only regret is I have only one +1 to give to this answer.

Comment: Wow! thanks! I really should take a class or something on this, i'm just learning via this forum and other net sources. What if i wanted to also check the target location for any duplicates of the href/src; if so, void? Thanks again, works perfect.